# Different GCC versions between yocto layers on same branch

Tags: stm32, yocto

I am following the [STM32MP1 and yocto tutorial by Shawn Hymel](https://www.digikey.ch/en/maker/projects/intro-to-embedded-linux-part-2-yocto-project/2c08a1ad09d74f20b9844e566d332da4) (tutorial is on the dunfell branch, I am trying to do it on mickledore). While configuring the kernel (command: `bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel`), I got the following error message:

```
ERROR: No recipes in default available for:

  /home/michael/yocto/meta-st-stm32mp/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-source_12.2.bbappend
```

While localising the files in question I noticed that the meta-st-stm32mp layer works with GCC v12.2 while the meta-devtools layer in poky uses v12.3. I expect this to be the source of the error.
The related files I have are

```
/home/michael/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-source_12.3.bb

/home/michael/yocto/meta-st-stm32mp/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-source_12.2.bbappend
```

1. Is the identified root cause of the error correct?
2. Is there something I can do about this other than waiting for st to update their bsp?

Comment: Just rename the bbappend file to the correct version to avoid this error. The bbappend applies one patch. Chances are that it will apply cleanly (it's just a minor version bump), though there is a small possibility that you will have to adapt it to the new version.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work (image is not fully tested yet)

Answer (score 1):

As skandigraun commented, the solution consisted in renaming the original `gcc-source_x.xx.bbappend` file to the one found in the `recipes-devtools/gcc` folder (`gcc-source_y.yy.bb`). Also, I had to add the `LICENSE="GPL"` field to the original file, otherwise yocto yields about it. Use there the appropriate license.